# Sails.js : Add custom instace method result as a model property

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

I'm relatively new to JavaScript programming, so this problem may have a trivial solution. Working with Sails.js, I've created this model.

```
module.exports = {

    tableName: 'FOO_TABLE',

    attributes: {
        FOO: 'string',
        BAR: 'number',
        BAR2: function() {
            return this.BAR + 1;
        }
    },

};
```

Then, in a controller I get all the instances:

```
FOO_MODEL.find().exec(function(err, FOOS) {
    return res.view({data: JSON.stringify(FOOS)});
});
```

The problem is that inside FOOS, it's not the BAR2 method. I've come with this solution (using Underscore.js):

```
FOOS = _.map(FOOS, function(FOO){ FOO.BAR2 = FOO.BAR2(); return FOO; });
```

But I don't see it efficient / smart, as I think I will probably find this problem again. How would you do it? Thank you

Comment: Can you give a little more detail as to what you're trying to accomplish?  Also, your `BAR2` instance method is probably not what you want--it currently adds "1" to a function object (`this.BAR2`).

Comment: Sorry, I typed it wrong, now it's fixed. I want to send all pairs key - value of the instances in JSON format, included the ones got from the methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all you want is to set a calculated value for each new instance, you could set `BAR2` to be of type `number` in the model (instead of a function), and add a `beforeCreate` class method like:

```
beforeCreate: function(values, cb) {
  values.BAR2 = values.BAR + 1;
  return cb();
}
```

If you want to keep `BAR2` as an instance method, but have it serialized along with the object, you could override the default `toJSON` instance method:

```
toJSON: function() {
   var obj = this.toObject();
   obj.BAR2 = obj.BAR2();
   return obj;
}
```

Any time an instance is stringified, its `toJSON` method will be called.

Comment: The first one is what I was looking for but the second is also very interesting for the future, thx!

Comment: workplace_branch: function(){
            return this.address_street_first + ' '+ this.address_street_second;
        },

        toJSON: function() {
            var obj = this.toObject();
            obj.workplace_branch = obj.workplace_branch();
            return obj;
        }

i get this error:
TypeError: Property 'workplace_branch' of object [object Object] is not a function

Answer (score 0):

#### Check Your Query Result

If you're calling your instance-method during a request, namely, within a query-callback -- you may want to check what result you are getting passed in.

In my case, I am using the Sails/Waterline ORM Model-method, `find` instead of `findOne` (like a bonehead), which actually argues a collection (**array**). So I was attempting something along the lines of:

`[ {...} ].hasItem(id)`

... while what I needed was something like:

`myQueryResults[0].hasItem(id)`

Or rather, query correctly using `findOne`. Idiocy is apparently a poor practice, but it happens I guess.

Hope this help!